# while loop error in retrieving data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database and i want to extract result based on two table of database .say tablea and tableb . php searches for particular id in tablea and if it is found  it has to do the work . it may be confusing here so i  will present my tabela and tableb structure here.i am showing the details for a particular user which i am filtering by where clause

```
tablea

id         userid
123         45
543         45
454         45
367         45
647         35
565         65


tableb

id        jid
23        123
24        123
25        123
4535      543
4536      543
4506      454
4507      454
```

etc

we can see that for a particular userid there may be several values in mysql tablea and for each id of tablea there may be several values in tableb id.please note that based on tablea id i want to present all data of tableb and please note that tablea id and tableb jid are same but in tableb jid will appear several times based on the number of times that occurs and for every time there will be new id in tableb. i have don e this query but it results only one output . i want to display all .

```
$res1 = sql_query("SELECT id from tablea  userid='{$user['id']}' order by id");

while ($row = sql_fetch_array($res1))
{
    $phid=$row['id'];
    {  
        $res2 = sql_query("select * from tableb where jid='{$phid}' order by id desc");

        $row2 = sql_fetch_array($res2);
        $d1 = $row2['id'];
        echo ' '.$d1.' ';      
    }
}​​​​​​
```

Comment: were those {} after $phid=$row['id']; on propose? If so, why?

Comment: You're missing `$` in the `{phid}` part of your second query - so even if the loop was working right, you're doing a where on a fixed string, not the $phid you retrieved from the first query.

Comment: You should set php to report errors. Place `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and
`ini_set('display_errors','On');` on top of all the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should make it. Although not very friendly.

```
$res1 = sql_query("SELECT id from tablea  userid='{$user['id']}' order by id");

while ($row = sql_fetch_array($res1)){
    $phid=$row['id'];  
    $res2 = sql_query("select * from tableb where jid='{phid}' order by id desc");
    while ($row2 = sql_fetch_array($res2)){                
        $d1 = $row2['id'];
        echo ' '.$d1.' ';      
    }
}​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 0):

This is much more easily done in one query:

#### Using an `IN ()` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM tableb WHERE jid IN (SELECT id FROM tablea WHERE userid='{$user['id']}');
```

#### Or with a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT
   tableb.*
FROM tablea JOIN tableb ON tablea.id = tableb.jid
WHERE tablea.userid = '{$user['id']}'
```

This simplifies the PHP to:

```
$userid = mysql_real_escape_string($user['id']);
$res = mysql_query(" SELECT tableb.* FROM tablea JOIN tableb ON tablea.id = tableb.jid WHERE tablea.userid = '{$userid}'");
if ($res) {
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
     echo $row['id'];
  }
}
```

Comment: it returns only one value i want 10 values to display so i was running while loop

Comment: @user1096307 This still uses a while loop to iterate over the result set. It will return as many rows for `jid` as there are. Try it and see.  Also test the query in a plain MySQL client. For example, by your example data, using userid=45 will return 7 rows.

Answer (score 0):

You should do in single query with `join` both tables.

```
SELECT ti.id,t2.id as t2id
FROM tablea as t1 LEFT JOIN tableb as t2 ON t1.id = t2.jid
WHERE t1.userid = '{$user['id']}'
```

Then make 2D array for showing multiple records of single user in tableb.

Like below :

```
$dataarray=array();
while ($row = sql_fetch_array($res1)) {
$dataarray['id'][]=$row['t2id'];
}
```